# Dynamic worksheet from 365 with custom columns

Tags: excel, dynamics-crm, export-to-excel, microsoft-dynamics

I’ve exported a Microsoft dynamics 365 file as dynamic worksheet where I’ve made some custom modifications in some columns right beside the dynamic columns (within same sheet). What I have experienced is that when I update the dynamic worksheet with new information gathered from dynamics365 it overwrites/deletes my custom columns. Looking in my ex colleagues work it should be possible to update the dynamic worksheet without loosing the custom columns within same sheet but I can’t figure out how to avoid the issue with deletion. Can anybody help?